org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass 2 tables, 3 classes
I have an error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass

It's thrown because I have two @Id annotations.
I have abstract class:
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTS")
public abstract class CommonProduct<Type extends AbstractProductUnderlying> extends HibernatePersistentObject implements Serializable, UniqueObject {
    @Ignore
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "products_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "products_seq", sequenceName = "products_seq")
    @Column(name = "productId")
    protected Integer productId;

I have second class without @Id which extends the one above and it's the same table:
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Product extends CommonProduct<ProductUnderlying> {

and there is third table which has different Id as CommonProduct:
@Entity(name = "viewProductHistory")
@Table(name = "PRODUCT_HISTORY")
public class ProductHistory extends CommonProduct<ProductUnderlyingHistory> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_HISTORY_ID")
    private int ProductHistoryId;

How can I solve it if two classes extends the one with @Id but one of them has different Id?

I highly doubt that you can have two id in one entity. Why do you want ProductHistoryId to by id?

no, no, ProductHistory has difference table than Product. One is writing to PRODUCT_HISTORY and second to PRODUCT

Then move  @Id from CommonProduct to Product and bob is your uncle.

I tried but got an exception: No identifier specified for entity: com.ubs.investor.cpss.domain.CommonProduct


Replace

@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTS")

on CommonProduct with
@MappedSuperclass


Remove @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
Put @Table(name = "PRODUCTS") where it belongs. Next to Product
Move productId from CommonProduct to Product


After call with colleague we did it the same way and it works. So already approved, thank you! Small adjustment in ProductHistory class productId must be read by @ManyToOne
